# debian v10 locale interpretation in date command

Tags: debian, date, locale

I've noticed that after upgrade from Debian 8 to Debian 10, the `date` command produces different (12H) format though the same LC_TIME is set on both.

It can also be easily demonstrated using LC_TIME in command line:

```
debian10# locale|grep LC_TIME
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
debian10# LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8" date
Tue 27 Oct 2020 12:14:56 PM UTC

debian8# locale|grep LC_TIME
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
debian8# LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8" date
Tue Oct 27 12:15:26 UTC 2020
```

When I try with en_GB.UTF-8 then the format is "correct" and the same as in Debian 8 with en_US.UTF-8:

```
debian10# LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8 date
Tue Oct 27 12:16:27 UTC 2020
```

Is there any way to change this functionality for en_US.UTF-8 in Debian 10?

Is it safe to change from en_US.UTF-8 to en_GB.UTF-8 in Debian 10 to get the same `date` output as in Debian 8?

Comment: Related: [serverfault.com/questions/977598](https://serverfault.com/questions/977598)

Comment: More related is Debian Bug #877900 , which M. Kitt or someone will no doubt enjoy putting into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by switching from `en_US.UTF-8` to `en_US`

```
# LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 date
Tue 27 Oct 2020 12:50:09 PM UTC
# LC_TIME=en_US date
Tue Oct 27 12:49:54 UTC 2020
```

Helpful command: `dpkg-reconfigure locales`